# Review Queue Tests in first posts need to be more sure before failing

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently received a test in the review queue, which I clearly knew was a test.  The user was blocked out and it suggested it could be spam.  I knew it was a valid question.

I didn't up vote I left a comment stating that it was a good post with relevant information, and it cause me to fail the test.

Why is a comment causing a fail? Clearly the review queue cannot understand the context of what a person may comment, so even if they are honing in on keywords, they still cannot interpret a comment.  Comments should not cause fails.

Answer (score 3):

> I didn't up vote I left a comment stating that it was a good post with relevant information

Well there's your problem.  You shouldn't be commenting just to say that a post is good.  That's what upvotes are for.  A comment like that is just noise.

Comment: I said with relevant information to the question, why is a potential answer considered incorrect?

Comment: @johnny5 No, saying, "good job" is not important information to include in a comment.  If you wish to convey that information, use the upvote button.  Your comment is just noise.

Comment: if they are asking a question, and you say "Great Post, I think you need to increment the X variable by 1" How is that not relevant? @Servy

Comment: @johnny5 First off, you should just omit the "great post", again, it's noise.  If you have an answer to the question, post an answer, don't try to answer it in comments, and it's also not what you should be doing from the review queue.  The review queue is where you help the author improve the quality of their posts, not where you try to answer them.  If you want to do that, leave the queue to do so.

Comment: Okay that makes sense,  but what if you were posting to clarify the question,   like what verision of SQL are you using.  The review queues are making the assumption that just because a person has a lot of upvotes, and a lot of points that means there post is perfect.  There can always be a valid comment on any post.  The only way the review queue should fail you for a review is if it can exactly decipher your comment understand the context were answering, which currently it does not.

Comment: @johnny5 Had you actually posted an appropriate comment, I would have some sympathy for you, but considering you didn't, I just don't.  You failed an audit for doing something wrong, so I'm really just not bothered by that.

Comment: That fine,  I didn't post this question for your sympathy it's obvious there is no way for the audit to be overturned.  I posted this question to point out a flaw with the way review audits are being done.  I'm assuming since your last comment was just noise, then you agree that although my specific comment wasn't valid,  that there was a possible comment that would be valid to not fail the audit and that the review system is flawed